# The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization

I'm trying to have `Internationalisation` in my project based on [this article](http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/tutorial.html) . but in `LanguageController.cs` file in `Language` method:

```
    public JavaScriptResult Language()
    {
        return GetResourceScript(Resources.Language.ResourceManager); //Error
    }
```

I get this error:

```
The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context
```

what's wrong whit It?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a `Resources.resx` file to your application. Also be careful to which folder you are adding it. For example the `App_GlobalResources` is a special ASP.NET folder and you should try placing your resx file somewhere else.

Comment: I added a file named 'resources.resx' and It gives this error ''MvcNewsAgent.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'Language'
'

Comment: Did you add a `Language` string to it? Also when you add a resx file, Visual Studio creates a corresponding C# file that allows you to access the constants in your code directly. There should be a `Resources.resx.designer.cs` file automatically generated for you.

Comment: I'm confused,that sounds like the Resource file should have language property.How can I define language for It?name/value strings have no effect.

Comment: Do you see the `.Designer.cs` file generated?

Comment: No, I mean that beneath your `Resources.resx` file there should be a `Resources.Designer.cs` file which was automatically generated by Visual Studio when you added the resx file. Also what are the properties of this resx file? Here's what you could do: right click on your project and select Add -> Resources file. Type `Resources` for the name and a `Resources.resx` and `Resources.Designer.cs` will be generated for you. Then add the `Language` key to your resx file in the designer and recompile. The `Custom Tool` associated to your resx file in the properties must be `ResXFileCodeGenerator`.

Comment: Well,U were right.I had to create a folder named Resources and a resource file named Language into It.

Comment: Commenting this because I had done many things such as deleting obj and bin folders, rebuilding and many others things, by adding another layout I got the Resources.designer to finally rebuild again, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Some times it happen when your activity namespace is not in the same name space as your Resource.Designer.cs file, or, the namespace is different of another activities.

Comment: I got this error after renaming a Xamarin.Forms Android project.  Afterwards I did a find/replace all on the new name of the project replacing the old with the new.  What I failed to do was to go into the android project properties and rename the assembly and the namespace like you said.  Then I did a find/replace once more and rebuilt successfully.  I also noticed the errors list remained even after a successful build.  I had to unload/reload the project for the errors to go away.

Comment: On the Mac I had to edit the csproj file of the Android project and change the name of the shared project csproj file it was trying to reference

Answer (score 1):

Old article from http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx (which is now dead):

### Resx Files In App_GlobalResources

Using resource files in `App_GlobalResources` from your controller code will break your unit tests.

When you drop a `.resx` file in the special `App_GlobalResources` folder, the IDE uses the `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator` to generate a strongly typed internal class to wrap the resources inside. The internal class gives any code in the MVC project access to the resources:

```
var greeting = Resources.Greeting;
```

You can also use the resources from a view:

```
@Html.Encode(Resources.Strings.Greeting)
```

The problem is that global resources are not actually embedded into the project’s .dll. Instead it is the ASP.NET runtime that creates an `App_GlobalResources` assembly with the resources inside. This assembly is referenced by all the view assemblies ASP.NET creates, and is explicitly loaded by the strongly typed wrapper generated by the `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator`. Since the `App_GlobalResources` assembly doesn’t exist without an ASP.NET compilation phase, it’s not available when unit tests are running. Controller code under test that tries to access the resources will bomb with an exception.

Note that you’ll also have some Intellisense problems when using the view syntax shown above. I'm guessing this is because the IDE is confused by seeing the resource wrapper in two places (the project assembly, and a wrapper also goes into the `App_GlobalResource` created by ASP.NET in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. ).

There is a way to make `resx` files in `App_GlobalResources` work, but the folder isn’t truly necessary in an MVC project (or a web application project, for that matter). I think it’s just as easy to add resx files in a different location, even a separate class library, to avoid any confusion on how `App_GlobalResources` will behave.

**In short:** avoid `App_GlobalResources` and `App_LocalResources` (which has its own set of problems) in MVC.

### Resx Files Outside Of Special Resource Directories

If you add a `resx` file to any other folder in an MVC project or class library, the `resx` is automatically set to be embedded into the project’s output assembly - this is good. The IDE also assigns the `resx` a custom tool of `ResxCodeFileGenerator` to generate a strongly typed wrapper - this is good. The generated class is internal by default – this is bad. The assembly created for a view (by ASP.NET) won’t be able to use the internal class because it is in a different assembly – the project assembly compiled in Visual Studio.

**Solution**

The easy fix is to make sure the custom tool is set to  `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` instead of `ResXCodeFileGenerator`. You can do this in the property window for the file, or in the resource editor that gives you a drop down for “Access Modifer” (the options are Internal, Public, and No Code Generation – choose Public).

[image]

You can also set the “Custom Tool Namespace” for the generated wrapper in the properties window. My suggestion is to use a convention like `“Resources”` for global resources, and `“Resources.Controller.View”` for resources dedicated to a specific view.

This approach means you can use the resources in unit-testable controller code, and in views, too. The syntax remains the same as above. The `ResouceManager` used in the wrapper classes can automatically resolve the proper resource to use depending on the current UI culture setting of the thread.

### Setting The UI Culture

The easiest approach to having the correct UI culture in effect during web request processing is to use the globalization section of `web.config`.

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>
```

The above will set both the current UI culture and current culture settings for the request.

If you need to set the culture up according to a user’s preference, or a URL parameter, then the best bet is to write a custom HTTP module or action filter.

### Have a dedicated localization folder for all the language files

If you want to put your `Resources.xx-YY.resx` files in a separate folder (i.e. `MyNamespace/Localization`), set the `Custom Tool Namespace` to just `MyNamespace` and then the Views will recognize the Resources files.

[image]

You might need to change the `Resources.Designer.cs` file as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been listed as answered, but the current answer actually didn't help me (since I had already followed that step). Just in case anyone else is searching and like me, isn't fully experienced, I had to add a line of code for each resource I was using to fix this problem. i.e.

```
var newName = NameSpace.Properties.Resources.resourceName;
```

Obviously replace newName, Namespace and resourceName accordingly for your own project. After using this I could reference the new variable and utilize it with my project. I might be out of line answering this 5 years late, but just in case another newbie runs into the same issue after successfully adding a new resource.